# OrientDB - JavaScript save/delete error

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB version: 2.2.x, Document database type.

I use JavaScript API for create/delete dynamic function but get error:

`Internal server error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Script pool for database 'myDataBase' is not configured`

My code for create dynamic functions:

```js
//  Using orient.getDatabase()
var db = orient.getDatabase();
var result = db.save({ "@class" : "OFunction", name : "DeleteMe", language: 'JavaScript', code: 'var res = [];', idempotent: true, parameters: ''});
db.commit();

// Or executeCommand
db.executeCommand('CREATE FUNCTION DeleteMe "print(\"Hello\");" IDEMPOTENT true LANGUAGE JavaScript');
```

This error I get when create or delete record from OFunction class. I tested similar code with other classes and didn't get same error. It is very stange.

Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've been able to reproduce your issue, but if you do a select from OFunction from Studio you can see that the funcion has been created. Anyway seems to be a bug, this is a similar issue: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6838

can you open an issue?

Comment: My colleague said that hi find login problem in OrientDB core